# how to Identify is there any addittion or deletion or same Object in new nested list compared to old nested list

Tags: java, list, arraylist

i have two lists as shown below.

```
List<Component> oldComps =getOldComps();
List<Component> newcomps=getNewComps();
```

corresponding POJOS are:

```
public class Component {  
 private List<Endpoint> endpoints;
}

public class Endpoint {
private String path;    
}
```

i have a use case where i need to identify:

---

1. is both newComps and oldComps Lists have same data or not ?
2. is there any **component added/deleted in newComps** which is not there in    oldcomps?if it is there that component details.
3. is there any **endponit added/deleted in any of newComps list component** which is not there in oldcomps list component?if it is there that endpoint details.

[newComps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBLgT.png)

[oldComps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uY30c.png)

**for detailed exaple** : as shown in attached images if oldComps and newComps 
==>contains same data.

Comment: Give definition of same data. Are we talking of same objects - Endpoints - "==" , or are we talking with same data in the sense of equals ?

Comment: If you can implement equals and hashCode for Component class, and then using Collections utiltity or Guava collection to find out answers for your questions

Answer (score 1):

Based on the presumption you have hashcode correct.

```
   HashSet oldComponentSet = new HashSet(oldComps);
    HashSet newComponentSet = new HashSet(newComps);
    //this line will give you intersection
    oldComponentSet.retainAll(setTwo);
    // this line will give you difference
    newComponentSet.removeAll(oldComponentSet)
    //united differfence based on presumption above two lines were not executed
    oldComponentSet.removeAll(newComponentSet).add(newComponentSet.removeAll(oldComponentSet));
```

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner my bad :) got too used to functional syntax. I will fix it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the hash code of your data structure which is a built-in function on many modern programming language to compare with another one.

You can get the result by calling the hashCode() method from the object that you want. In your case, oldComps.hashCode() will give you the result.

For further: [hashCode() by Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-hashcode)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.equals()` method to compare the two lists.

To find any component which is not in the other list you can use `.removeAll()` method of `List` class to identify the unique element.